# Ошибка в использовании метода

Tags: синтаксис, c++

```
if (RegOpenKeyEx(hKeyRoot, **Subkey.c_str()**, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE , &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {                   
        if (RegDeleteKey(hKey, **ValueKey.c_str()** ) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            bReturn = true;
        }
    }
```

Выдает ошибку:
error C2228: left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union

Пишу на с++ в VS2010. В чем может быть косяк? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Kitty2312, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Наверное, у вас Subkey и ValueKey и так являются С-string-ами.    Соответственно, с_str не нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error C2228 google go go go

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3y365xw6(v=vs.90).aspx